# Fix a id in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery for my application.
Having a doubt on how to add an id to my element tr.

My code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        var td1 = document.createElement('td');
        tr.appendChild(td);
    });
</script>
```

I am trying to add an id to the tr element

like

EDIT :
by `$(tr).attr('id', 'entryRow'+increment);`
And resolved..Thanks

Comment: There's really no need to edit the question and adding "EDIT : by $(tr).attr('id', 'entryRow'+increment); And resolved..Thanks". Just accept the answer that helped solving you problem, and take note of the other answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since tr is not a jQuery object, you will have to write as below:

```
$(tr).attr('id', 'NewIdValue');
```

If you have more than one attributes to be set, you can write as below (using Json Notation):

```
$(tr).attr( {
    id: 'newIdValue',
    name: 'newName'     
  } );
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use pure JavaScript to create elements, jQuery has a handy interface for that too. try:

```
$("<tr id='newId'><td></td></tr>")
```

See also: http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#htmlownerDocument

Answer (score 2):

If you have even more data to associate with one row, you could use data structore to store that data:

```
$(tr).data('key', anything);
var any = $(tr).data('key');
```